# Capturing Draggable Events

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to capture Draggable events in order to apply animation whenever Drag Action get cancelled by user or offset get updated.

In particular this callbacks

onDraggableCanceled → DraggableCanceledCallback
Called when the draggable is dropped without being accepted by a DragTarget. [...]

void DraggableCanceledCallback (
Velocity velocity,
Offset offset
)
Signature for when a Draggable is dropped without being accepted by a DragTarget.

Used by Draggable.onDraggableCanceled.

Comment: Does GestureDetector help you?

Comment: I saw example on using GestureDetecor, does it replace built-in Draggable widgets?